# state for one or more table in DB with EJB3

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

hy all, 
we suppose we have many entity A, B, C ,D
when i call ejb bean for save new entity or update entity, i would like found a mode for verify if not another managed Bean thread has save a new entity A or B or C or D or has update one or mode for verify if a table is modified when i m in transaction
because when i like save new Entity A has a many field integer depend for haw match specific entity B and c and d is saved in DB

```
@Stateless
public class EntityABean implements EntityARemote, EntityALocal {

@Resource
 private SessionContext context;

@EJB
private DaoEntity daoEntityEjb;

public void doSomthing(Object param1, Object param2 ...) {
try {
 //dosomthing
}
catch(Excepyion ex) {
context.rollback();
throw ex;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but from what I can make out is that you probably need automatic Optimistic Concurrency control mechanism of JPA.
You need to annotate your version column as explained [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#Example_of_Version_annotation) and the rest is taken care of by the underlying JPA compliant provider.
For more details you can take a look at another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120043/optimistic-locking-by-concrete-java-example).

You can further control the way JPA manages locking on a versioned entity by specifying a lock mode. You do this through the lock() method of the EntityManager class. Here is the method signature:

```
public void lock(Object entity, LockModeType lockMode);
```

For more explanation take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581603/jpa-and-optimistic-locking-modes)

Comment: i know that, my problem i like found mode observer o another for i call it for i can have information if during my transaction there is not another thread has update or save new entity. Another solution is : all metode call one metode syncro for i can garanted all entity is not modified or is new one is saved when i m in the metode

Comment: the solution is in EJB3.1 when i can use session @singleton how i guaranted the access is syncro for all methode in this beans